# How to mock a class and setup a method to return a private variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Well this seemed to be trivial before i started this, but i cant get it to work.

This code is the essential elements of the problem.

I have a class with a private variable which i can retrieve the value of by calling a method.

```
public class CheckItOut {
  private bool authenticated = false;

  public CheckItOut(){}

  public bool IsAuthenticated(){
    return authenticated;
  }
}
```

Then i have a testclass which mocks this class, and injects it via constructor into the class which im testing.

```
.
.
.
Mock<CheckItOut> mockedCheckItOut = new Mock<CheckItOut>();
mockedCheckItOut.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated()).Returns(true);
Controller sut = new Controller(mockedCheckItOut);
.
.
.
```

When i step through the test code and reach the .Setup, i get the following error

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: x => x.IsAuthenticated()
Non-overridable members (here: CheckItOut.IsAuthenticated) may not be used in setup
```

I don't understand. Im not doing anything to any members of CheckItOut. Im mocking/replacing a method call with my own implementation returning true.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong ?

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: Mocking should be performed on an interface, not on a class.  There are ways to mock methods on a class, but it is not what you are meant to be doing so best to avoid it.  So create an interface for your class, and then mock that

Comment: Thank you. I did that earlier, but then i cant send the CheckItOut object to the class im testing. Compiler tells me that it cant convert from ICheckItOut to CheckItOut.

Comment: The class you're testing should be using the interface as well, not the class. You should generally be using dependency injection to provide the concrete implementation of the interface at run time. That's how you're able to provide an instance of your `CheckItOut` in the application and the mock object in the test. Both objects implement the interface so that's all the consumer cares about.

Comment: Based on the error message, it sounds like you could mock the class method if you declared it `virtual`, although I'm not 100% sure that would work. Regardless, you should be using the interface everywhere, using DI/IoC to provide the concrete implementation at run time and then mocking that interface in your tests.

Comment: Okie. Ive created the interface, and the tested class is injected with an interface object. But what im creating is a Mock<ICheckItOut> object and the class needs to be injected with an ICheckItOut object. How do i solve that ? Sry im a bit new to mocking..

Comment: Ahh think i got it. Its the mockedObject.Object i have to pass on :) TY for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to mock a non virtual member/function of your class. That is something that Moq (or any mocking framework) cannot do.
If you want to mock your class you have to define the IsAuthenticated function as virtual.

An even better way to have more control over your objects in tests is to use interfaces for your classes. This way you're able to mock all of the public behaviour of your objects for the tests.

Comment: Thank you i just did that, and got it to work...